# Mysql row always = 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello i am trying to check to see if there is a row in the db but for some resson it keeps saying there is but is not. I have loads of if staments in side one so i think that is the problem.

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['A'])) {
$item2= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['A']);
$item = strip_tags($item2);

$pokemonchoice= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['B']);
$pokemonchoicee = strip_tags($pokemonchoice);



?><?php  
 if ( $pokemonchoicee == "Add to pokemon 1" ) {
    $pokemonchoicee = '1';
}
 if ( $pokemonchoicee == "Add to pokemon 2" ) {
    $pokemonchoicee = '2';
}
 if ( $pokemonchoicee == "Add to pokemon 3" ) {
    $pokemonchoicee = '3';
}
 if ( $pokemonchoicee == "Add to pokemon 4" ) {
    $pokemonchoicee = '4';
} 
 if ( $pokemonchoicee == "Add to pokemon 5" ) {
    $pokemonchoicee = '5';
}
 if ( $pokemonchoicee == "Add to pokemon 6" ) {
    $pokemonchoicee = '6';
}

 ?>

 <?php


 $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item='".$item."' AND belongsto='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0)
{
echo "You do not have this item";
}
else
{
echo "You have this item";
}

 ?>

 <?php
 echo $pokemonchoicee ;
 echo $item ;
 }

 ?>
```

The bit which keeps printing true is

```
 <?php


 $query = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE item='".$item."' AND belongsto='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
if(mysql_num_rows($query)!=0)
{
echo "You do not have this item";
}
else
{
echo "You have this item";
}

 ?>
```

I remove all rows but still says You have this item

Comment: Still getting You do not have this item when the item is there,,,

Comment: Changing that line would, of course, give you the other echo message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_num_rows()` gets a mysql result type resource, use `$query = mysql_query($query)` before mysql_num_rows

Comment: Alternatively, you could use mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query))

Comment: Just read your edit and now it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your if statement. If the number of rows returned are > 0, you're printing "You do **not** have this item". It should be the other way around, so change the `!=` check or let the echoes switch places